# More than one admin logged in?

Tags: wp-admin

Is it said that if there are more than one admin logged in 
into wordpress can cause the host to overload ?

I made some test, and the results are :
If there is one admin the dashboard response is more
quick and smooth, but if there are more and i try
to access a certain taxonomy example post categories 
the host overloads to the max.

Is there anyway to investigate what is causing this ?
and are there any optimization required ?
What can i do to make wordpress faster and not to overload
the host ?

Comment: What is the logic behind this question? You need to upgrade your hosting

Comment: @Aniket the logic of this question is that does the logged in admins have this great impact on wordpress performance or not ?

Comment: Obviously the answer will be yes!